# Javascript IIFE, don't understand how this variable becomes global

Tags: javascript, iife

Take the following block of code. There is no return statement, and yet MyApp.VideoTracker is a property on the window object and so is accessible globally.

```
 (function(window, $, VideoTracker, undefined) {
    "use strict";

    VideoTracker.loadAPI = function(apiReadyCallbackFn) { 
    };

    VideoTracker.destroy = function(iframeElement) { 
    };

    VideoTracker.trackVideos = function() {
    };

    $().ready(function() {
        var youTubeIframes = $('iframe[src*="youtube.com"]');
        if (youTubeIframes.length > 0) {
            VideoTracker.loadAPI(VideoTracker.trackVideos);
        }
    });

}(window, jQuery, MyApp.VideoTracker = MyApp.VideoTracker || {}));
```

Is this because of the way it is defined in the function call, i.e.:

```
MyApp.VideoTracker = MyApp.VideoTracker || {}
```

An explanation would be great, as I can see this must be the reason but don't understand why?

Comment: Well yes, it is indeed an assignment. Just pass MyApp.VideoTracker || {}. Yet where the MyApp comes from is the question.

Comment: for that to work, `MyApp` must already be on the window object ... in other words, at that point in the code `MyApp` === `window.MyApp` ... if `MyApp` were not on the window object, your code would fail to run, with a `ReferenceError: MyApp is not defined` error

Comment: Cool MyApp is already a property on window. I didn't realize you could assign in a function call

Comment: @Lain - for that to work, `MyApp` must already be on the window object, or the same error will occur ... furthermore, the `VideoTracker.*` functions would be confined to the IIFE, which could be fine, but what's the point of `.destroy`, it's unreferenced

Comment: @Jaromanda X: That is correct. Yet I wrongly assumed the OP was well aware of that and wondering about the actual .VideoTracker.

Comment: @Lain - I get what you're saying

Comment: Ok, and so because all I have passed is a reference to Window.MyApp.VideoTracker, then any properties I add within the function get attached to the global object rather than a copy that is only accessible from within the IIFE

Comment: @DavidB: Yes in a way. You could pass JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(MyApp.VideoTracker)) to have an actual copy of it - depending on what the object is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, essentially you're calling the IIFE with what are global variables.

Assuming you've defined `MyApp` already - and before the function body is executed - you're calling it with an expression that either sets the `VideoTracker` property of `MyApp` with the existing `MyApp.VideoTracker` or an empty object literal, and that reference is being passed into your IIFE.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

That's because your ***MyApp*** is a Global object already- it doesn't become one, because of your self invoked function.

- How else do you think you would be able to access its *VideoTracker* property or define it if it's not there?
- In a case in which *MyApp* object doesn't exist as a part of a higher context in which your IIFE is being executed, it should rise a *Reference Error!* because *MyApp object* is neither defined, nor being created within your given IIFE context.